# PHImageResultIsDegradedKey is not working, how can I find out if PHAsset is in low quality?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, photo

I want to find out if a PHAsset (picture) is stored in high quality on the iDevice or if I'll have to download it later on if I want full quality

The way I did it was to use the PHImageManager with the following options

```
PHImageRequestOptions * options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeFastFormat;
options.synchronous = NO;
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
options.networkAccessAllowed = NO;
```

Then, I use the default PHImageManager and do the following request

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:self options:options resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
        NSNumber *isDegraded = info[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey];
```

My problem is that isDegraded bool value is always false even when the image is optimised on the device from an iCloud photo album. Thus, the data from the request will give 50kb of data if optimised then I go in the photo App open the photo fullscreen and when I execute the same data request later on it is 1Mb. isDegraded has the same value false in both cases. Any tip on this? Is it a bug from Apple Photo Framework ?

Comment: I also submitted a bug report 19362883

Comment: Do you see this problem with Photostreams or also with the "iCloud Photo" beta images?
I have the same problem sometimes, but it seems to be limited to (shared) photostreams.

For not yet downloaded iCloud Photo beta images, isDegraded is working for me.

Comment: @Thyraz I see it for iCloud Photo beta images and Shared Albums. Not sure about the Photostream question. My solution so far has been to measure the size in pixel of the image to find out if it's a thumbnail or a full res image